# How to unchecked all checkboxes except checkboxes in a table whose id is passed as a variable to a function using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to unchecked all checkboxes except checkboxes in a table whose id is passed as a variable to a function using jquery

Comment: sounds like a puzzle. normally some code will help.

Comment: I have a table where in each row I have column with checkboxes in a table and I would like to uncheck checkboxes from all rows except the checkboxes in a table of current row.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(':checkbox:not(#'+idvar+')').prop('checked',false);
```

where `idvar` contains the id of the checkbox you do not want to uncheck.

Comment: except checkboxes in a table whose id is passed as a variable to a function

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table").find(":checkbox").removeAttr("checked").end().find("checkboxid").attr("checked","checked");
```

Comment: except checkboxes in a table whose id is passed as a variable to a function